# Can I use Blender 3.0 Alpha for some projects and 2.93 for others?

Tags: interface

Can I have 2 versions of Blender at the same time?

So if I download Blender 3.0 Alpha for one specific project, will I still be able to go back and open my old .blend files in version 2.93? I just don't want to lose any of my old projects.

Comment: There is a 50% chance to mess your file if you use an unrelease version, because is still under development and probably buggy, you could try to make two version if you still want to use and alpha version. One to use and one back up in order to use a with stable version only.

Comment: You might be able to **just** open them but chances are high you're not gonna do much with them.

Comment: 2.93 files should open fine in 3.0, but 3.0 files **might** not open correctly in 2.93. So if you open, edit and save a 2.93 (or earlier) file in 3.0 it may no longer open correctly in 2.93.

Comment: People who beta test blender do this all the time, and there are even utilities around that let you select which version of blender you want to use to open a file.  It is not unusual to have 3 or 4 versions at a time, because a lot of us are in the same situation you are. (I've got 2.79, 2.83LTS, 2.93LTS and 3.0alpha on this system.)  But @JohnEason is right.  If you ever accidentally open a 2.93 file in 3.0 and then save it, you might not be able to use it in 2.93 anymore.  It's rare than 50% but it does happen.